# My save files are not located in my Skyrim folder. Where are they?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Recently I've been playing on my home PC and I was having a blast but due to some unforeseen circumstances I had to go away for a couple of days, so I copied my whole Skyrim folder and put it in my hard drive. But when I tried running it on a different computer there were no saves. My saves are not recorded in the folder itself. How can I locate my saves?

Comment: Documents is usually the first place I'd look for any user documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Documents\My Games\Skyrim\Saves` or `My Documents\My Games\Skyrim\Saves` if you're on Windows XP or below.